# Display a custom link in Django Admin edit item view?

Tags: django, django-admin

Here's a piece of Django admin interface's instance edition form:

[image]

How should I change the underlying `admin.ModelAdmin` instance to make it contain an URL, like this?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Django makes this easy. Subclass `ModelAdmin`, add a custom method and then tell the Admin how to use it. Here's a sample `admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Vendor

class VendorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ['example_link']

    def example_link(self, obj):
        return '<a href="{}">link text</a>'.format(obj.get_link())  # however you generate the link
    example_link.allow_tags = True

admin.site.register(Vendor, VendorAdmin)
```

Here's the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields) that furthers explains `readonly_fields`, customizing the form label text with `short_description`, ordering, and how you can put this custom url method on the `Model` or `ModelAdmin`.

Comment: For the newer Django versions, use: 
`from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe` and then
`return mark_safe('<a href="#">link text</a>')` instead of `example_link.allow_tags = True`

Comment: @AnoopNair Thanks. It works for Django==3.1.